# How to check what congestion algorithm supported on my linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, tcp

I want to enable google bbr on my VPS. But I don't know this feature is integrated on linux kernel or not. How can I check it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add TCP congestion control variant to Linux Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278215/add-tcp-congestion-control-variant-to-linux-ubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below command used to find the available tcp congestion control algorithms supported.

**1. `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_available_congestion_control`**

```
bic reno cubic
```

**2. This command used to find which tcp congestion control configured for your Linux.**

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control
```

**3. Below command is used to change to desired one from the available list.**

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=bic
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_available_congestion_control
```

Comment: Do you mind expanding on this answer a bit so that it is more clear for anyone that stumbles across this thread in the future?

Answer (score 0):

You can check your system conf by command `sysctl -a`. 
By using `sysctl -a | grep tcp_congestion_control` command, your can check your current tcp_congestion_control algorithm.

If your system supported bbr, the result will like this:

`net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control = bbr`

Comment: This is wrong. This gives the algorithm currently used, not all algorithms supported by the kernel

Comment: @GavinS.Yancey Yes, Kigo's answer looks better.